# How to call javascript (or jQuery) on page load (update/change) in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have the page for creating some object. On this page if user checked checkbox, the hidden area with some text fields will appear. Then when user will try to submit object, server can send a validation errors so the user will need to correct some fields. THE PROBLEM IS that when this happens, area with additional fields becomes hidden again (But checkbox is checked, so user need to uncheck and then check it again). So is it possible to call this function every time something changes or server send me an error?
For showing and hiding additional section I am using this jQuery code:

```
function changeVisibilityOfCreateCustomerSection() {
            if ($("#isnewcustomer").prop("checked") == true) {
                $(".saf-createcustomersection > div > input").prop("disabled", false);
                $(".saf-createcustomersection").show();
            } else {
                $(".saf-createcustomersection > div > input").prop("disabled", true);
                $(".saf-createcustomersection").hide();
            }
        }
```

I am calling it this way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.isNewCustomer,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new {
                            @class = "checkBox",
                            onchange = "changeVisibilityOfCreateCustomerSection();",
                            id = "isnewcustomer" } })
```

I was trying to use something like this in javascript tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            changeVisibilityOfCreateCustomerSection();
        });

        $(window).load(function () {
            changeVisibilityOfCreateCustomerSection();
        });
```

But these functions are not working at all. I should say that page is partial and body tag is in shared layout, so I don't sure whether it is good practice to call such functions in onload for body tag or something like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your partial page loads you can use the Page_Load to do the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   // checks here if the page is loaded normally not with a submission to the server from the same page
   if(!IsPostBack){
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "functionName()", true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where should I place it? (I am using MVC pattern in project)